# TabControl Child is loaded twice but the first time does not trigger SelectionChangedEvent

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a user control.

```
<UserControl>

    <UserControl.DataContext>
      <vm:VmCatalogItems/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid>
      <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Base Produts" MinWidth="150">
          <vi:ViBaseProducts/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Packages">
          <vi:ViPackages/>
        </TabItem>
      </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Where the child ViPackages UserControl is like below.

```
<UserControl>

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PackageTypesLoaded}" />
      </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <Grid>

      <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PackageTypes}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPackageType}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PackageTypeSelectedAsync}" />
          </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
      </ComboBox>

    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

When first UserControl is loaded it fires the loaded event. If the user selects the packages tab it fires the loaded event again. This seems to be a problem for me because it fires the below method twice. I intended this method to trigger the SelectionChanged event but it only triggers it the second time it loads. But since it sets it to the FirstOrDefault the first time it loads it does not trigger it the second time it loads. SO the PackageTypeSelectedAsync command never fires.

```
private void PackageTypesLoaded()
{
  SelectedPackageType = PackageTypes.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

I want to make it so either the method is not called the first time or the SelectionChanged event is fired the first time. But I can not seem to figure a way yet.

Comment: You should bind itemssource of your tabcontrol and template out that collection into items. You would then have your data in the viewmodels. Go back to a different tab and your old data would be there. You could then get your default data when you build out your viewmodels initially.

Comment: If you used the community mvvm toolkit you can implement a method for OnSelectedPackageChanged, use that to get your data and lose your selectionchanged handler.

Answer (score 0):

The `Loaded` event is raised each time the tab is selected and the `UserControl` is loaded into the element tree.

If you only want to execute your code once on the initial load, you could use a variable to detect whether the control has previously been loaded, e.g.:

```
private bool _hasBeenLoaded = false;
private void PackageTypesLoaded()
{
    if (!_hasBeenLoaded)
    {
        SelectedPackageType = PackageTypes.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    _hasBeenLoaded = true;
}
```

For the command, you could invoke it directly in your method or in the setter of the `SelectedPackageType` property instead of handling the `SelectionChanged` event in the view:

```
private void PackageTypesLoaded()
{
    SelectedPackageType = PackageTypes.FirstOrDefault();
    PackageTypeSelectedAsync.Invoke(null);
}
```